# How to hide a Published Articles on Author's WordPress Dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

When my Authors Published Articles or when I publish author's pending article, I want to hide those published posts from their admin panel post list. (Those articles still belong to them, I Only Want to Hide articles from their admin panel.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pre_get_posts` to customize the query in the WordPress. Eg:

```
function theme_slug_customize_admin_query( $query ) {
  if ( is_admin() ) {
    $query->set( 'author', get_current_user_id() );
    $query->set( 'post_status', array( 'draft' ) );
  }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'theme_slug_customize_admin_query' );
```

In the above example, some query parameters are modified. Author is set to currently loggedin user and post status is set to draft. This will only display post by the author and those posts which are not published.